# R generating binary matrix with no identical rows

Tags: r, binary, binary-matrix

For a matrix of `M` by `N` containing just 0 and 1, how to make no identical rows exists. For example, if `N = 3` and `M = 3`, one solution is:

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

I know using some exhausive permutation algorithm works, but I am thinking is there any better solution since `M < 2^N` is the common case.

Comment: View each row as a number in binary. As long as each row is a unique binary number, it will be unique. So get numbers, `sample(0:(2^N - 1), size = M, replace = FALSE)`, convert them to binary strings (with leading zeros) and split the strings into the columns of your matrix.

Comment: @Gregor Looks pretty neat. But why I need leading zeros?

Comment: got it, to make each row have same number of elements.